# React Native app lagging when brought back to foreground

Tags: performance, react-native

I'm getting a loooong (about 10s) lag when bringing my React Native app to the foreground after leaving it in the background for any length of time.

The whole app is simply frozen.

What could be causing this? What is the best way to debug and isolate the problem?

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.9",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-fabric-digits": "github:jeanlebrument/react-native-fabric-digits",
    "react-native-firebase-analytics": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.22.9",
    "react-native-invertible-scroll-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-swipe-cards": "github:nicholasstephan/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards",
    "url-regex": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your app is in development mode ?

Comment: No. This is after deployment. Seeing this freezing on TestFlight and App Store releases.

Comment: have you integrated crash log files in your app?

Comment: No. Don't think so.

Comment: can i see your package.json?

Comment: Added my package.json above. Could one of those packages be causing the delay. It's a pretty light app. My biggest concern is memory. In XCode I'm seeing the app sit around 400mb of memory usage. That doesn't feel excessive to me, but could that be the issue?

Comment: Is your build is really in release mode ?

Comment: I don't think that much of memory leak is possible

Comment: Yes. Running in debug mode. But where this is happening is after archiving, which shows as "release" in Edit Scheme. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141390/discussion-between-codesingh-and-nicholas).

Comment: were you able to solve this? Having a similar issue.